# Add/remove reactive form validators to dynamically created inputs

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have created a form in Angular 4, which allows the user to click an ADD or REMOVE button in the form to add/remove fields to the form.  I use ngFor to create the html inputs on screen from an array (enlarged by the add function, or shrunk by the remove function).

In the html template I can add formControlName in the form formControlName="control{{index}}" to ensure each new input has a formcontrol.

But how do I dynamically **add and remove validators** for these inputs?

Comment: Possibly similar to this? ► https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175411/how-to-add-a-validator-dynamically-to-a-formcontrol-in-angular-2

Answer (score 65, accepted):

can you look at this document https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity,

for add/remove controls you can use these methods

> addControl/removeControl

for value and validators you can use like this

```
 this.form.controls['test_control'].setValidators([Validators.required])
 this.form.controls['test_control'].updateValueAndValidity()
```

Comment: I don't see these functions listed on the document you referenced (though they look encouraging).

Answer (score 3):

**Source [Link](https://thecodemon.com/angular-dynamically-toggle-the-required-from-form-controls/)**

For Angular 11 Use **setValidators()** and **updateValueAndValidity()** methods

```
  setRequired() {
    this.profileForm.controls.firstName.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    this.profileForm.controls.firstName.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  unsetRequired() {
    this.profileForm.controls.firstName.setValidators(null);
    this.profileForm.controls.firstName.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

Comment: This works to a certain extent. The downside is that setValidators(null) will remove all other validations that have been set as well.

Answer (score 3):

*****Angular 13. It's working for me...*****

**OnInit Func:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form.get('type')?.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      if (val) {
        switch (val) {
          case 1:
            this.removeValidators(['comment', 'id']);
            this.addValidators(['desc', 'options']);
            break;
          case 2:
            this.removeValidators(['desc', 'options', 'comment']);
            this.addValidators(['id']);
            break;
        }
      }
    });
}
```

**Func (Add/Remove Validators):**

```
addValidators(controls : string[]){
    controls.forEach(c => {
        if(['desc','comment'].includes(c)){
            this.form.get(c)?.setValidators([Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(250)]);
        } else {
            this.form.get(c)?.setValidators(Validators.required);
        }
        this.form.get(c)?.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
}

removeValidators(controls : string[]){
    controls.forEach(c => {
        this.form.get(c)?.clearValidators();
        this.form.get(c)?.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you man. .updateValueAndValidity(); is very important in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why nobody has posted this yet... but in Angular 16 you can use the `addValidators()` method.

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#addvalidators